# Data variable from API fetch function not working when declared

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch-api

I'm really new to js and I already have to work with APIs and use async/await so I *know* there might be something I don't get here...

Here's my code:

```
async function collectWorks() {
    const response = await fetch ("http://localhost:5876/api/works");
    const worksData = await response.json();
    return worksData
}

async function testfunction() {
    await collectWorks();
    let test = worksData[1].title;
    console.log(test)
}
testfunction()
```

Here's my problem: I have my async function to fetch my API. I should get the data in my **const worksData**, correct? But when I try to use it in my **testfunction** it doesn't work and I get this in the console :

*Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: worksData is not defined at testfunction*

However, and that's what I don't understand, when I get rid of the **const** in front of worksData it works perfectly and I do get the result I need... What did I miss? Am I not supposed to declare it?

(I actually noticed this because at first I forgot to add the const and went on with my project because it worked fine. When I noticed, I tried to add it back but it broke everything. I ended up starting anew because I thought rest of the code might be messing with it but now I can't even start since I'm stuck with this problem... I've tried declaring it before the fetch function too.)

Comment: You have to assign the result of `await collectWorks()` to the variable `worksData` if you want to use it in `testfunction()`. It is declared as a local variable in `collectWorks()` and so it is not accessible from `testfunction()`.

Comment: The reason it worked when you omitted `const` is because when you initialize a variable without it, it became a global variable and therefore was accessible in all functions within the script. Some more info on local vs global variables can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the return value of the function:

```
await collectWorks();
```

If you want the return value to be in a variable called `worksData` (or called anything at all really), store that value in a variable:

```
let worksData = await collectWorks();
```

(*Exactly* as you already do for `response` and `worksData` within the `collectWorks` function.)

---

> when I get rid of the const in front of worksData it works perfectly and I do get the result I need

Because without the variable declaration (only the assignment), it's an *implicit global*.  Basically it becomes a property on the `window` object.  Which is best to avoid in general.